# how to find and replace in python by indexing wise or in sequence wise

Tags: python, excel, indexing, regexp-replace

I am new in software and very much newbie with python, I have a large text file (data.txt) which contain a very long string, Inside file data should be like = `fghj123321fghjhgfj213fghh22131132132fghfgjhgf3123fhghfhfh313213hgh12hggj12313fjfhgjfhgf131gjgj1313fhfh`
and want to replace with given code in excel file (code.xlsx) and it's contain code for replace in data.txt
code.xlsx should similar to like this in column 'A' fgh123j, and in column 'B' xx012 so in data file fgh123j with replace with xx012.

For better clarity lets assume, if data.txt is like = `1231321233123312231233121231231231312222312131112312312123312333321321321321`. and in excel file (code.xlsx) having in Column 'A' = 111, 112, 113, 121, 122, 123, 133, 131, 132, 211..., and in Column 'B' = xx001, xx002, xx003 xx004, xx05, xx006, xx007, xx008, xx009, xx010...., so if we will use random find and replace it will change first all of 111 than 112 than 113, but it will mess up the whole file.

so I want to pick only first three digit from data.txt (for example 123) and replace with it's replacement code available in code.xlsx, (for example xx006) than it pick 2nd three digits from data.txt (for example 132) and change with it's replacement code available in code.xlsx, (for example xx009), the operation can continue till the end of string. As per my requirement,

I am pretty much sure it can be done with of regex, but not having knowledge.
I tried but it through error.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import re
os.chdir('C:/New folder')

with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    string = f.read()

df4 = pd.read_excel("code.xlsx", header=None, index_col=False, dtype=str)
df4.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C']

for index, row in df4.iterrows():
    string = re.compile('.{1,3},', string)
    regex = re.compile(row['A'])
    read_file = regex.sub((row['C']), read_file)
    write_file = open('data.txt', 'w')
    write_file.write(read_file)
```

Comment: Could you make example of what you need to achieve? Give an example of small input data, a small number of excel lines, and a resulting string.

Comment: want to make change in text file via excel file, but index wise, if contain in my text file is =1231321233123312231233121231231, and code in excel file is in column A  (1row) = 123,   column A  (2row) = 112,column A  (3row) = 132 and in column B  (1row) = xx01,   column B  (2row) = xx002, column B  (3row) = xx003.. so when I start replacing operation so it pick only first 3 digits and replace code, then next 3 digit and replace, after first replace =  =xx00113212331233122, after second replace =  xx001xx00312331233122.it should continues till end of text file = xx001xx003xx.....

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be kind of solution

```
import os
import pandas as pd

with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    string = f.read()

df4 = pd.read_excel("code.xlsx", header=None, index_col=False, dtype=str)
df4.columns = ['A', 'B']
m = dict()
for index, row in df4.iterrows():
    m[row['A']] = row['B']

out = ''
for i in range(0, len(string), 3):
    idx = string[i, i+3]
    try:
        out += m[idx]
    except IndexError:
        out += idx
   
with open('data_out.txt', 'w') as write_file
    write_file.write(out)
```

P.S. I did not test this code - it is just a scketch

Comment: error [i, i+3], Expected type 'Union[int, slice]', got 'Tuple[int, List[int]]' instead

Comment: Yeah, this is just a scatch of solution. Some bugs should be fixed.